# NameError: free variable 'list' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, data-mining, data-manipulation

I am trying to code a Decimal Scaling function which receives a list of lists as input parameter.

```
def decimal_scale(data):
    #calculate the maximum absolute value for each attribute
    grouped_attributes = [list(attributes) for attributes in zip(*data)]

    #absolute list of list grouped attributes
    absolute_attributes = []
    for item in grouped_attributes:
        list = []
        for i in range(0, len(item)):
            list.append(abs(item[i]))
        absolute_attributes.append(list)

    max_att_val = []
    for abs_att_list in absolute_attributes:
        abs_att_list.sort()
        max_att_val.append(abs_att_list[-1])

        #calculate the appropriate k for each attribute
    k_attributes = []
    for max in max_att_val:
        k = 0
        while max/(10**k) > 1:
            k+=1

        k_attributes.append(k) #appropriate ks for all the Attributes

    res = []
    for item in data:
        res.append([item[i]/(10**(k_attributes[i])) for i in range(0, len(item))])
    return res
```

When I run this code I get the **error**:

File "mynormalize.py", line 39, in

```
grouped_attributes = [list(attributes) for attributes in zip(*data)]
```

> NameError: free variable 'list' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

Can somebody please suggest a way to fix this? And maybe a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a list `list = []`, change the name of this list and it has to work